# How do I filter text in a column in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, regex

I have a column that contains text and numbers in the same cell.

I want to return all the rows from a column that contain both the number 1 and the number 2.

I tried using `=regexmatch(E1,"1|2")` and also `=match(E1, {"1","2"}, 0)` but they both failed.

Comment: Please add a sample of your data.  Would you want to return `John1Bo2b` or only `12`, `21`, or only `1` or `2` or `John1Bob or ` `1JohnBob`, or `John 1`  etc. etc.

Comment: Please clarify specifically what you mean by *"they both failed"*.  Did you get an unexpected result,? Did you get an error?  Did it return the right result but only for one row?  etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Data > Create a filter**, make your filter condition refer to the first *data* cell, like this:

```
=regexmatch(E2, "\b1\b") * regexmatch(E2, "\b2\b")
```

To get the matching rows in another column, use a `filter()` formula, like this:

```
=filter(E2:E, regexmatch(E2, "\b1\b"), regexmatch(E2, "\b2\b"))
```

Comment: Don't want to write an answer as my formula would be the same however my read of the question is that the RegEx should be `"1.*2|2.*1"`  (any cell containing both 1 and 2 anywhere in the value.  The question isn't clear however "1 or 2 preceded by and followed by a word boundary" seems like a broad interpretation.  Assumes the numbers are not part of strings or larger numbers.  Hopefully, they clarify what they want and what "failed"

Comment: Edited the answer to require that both numbers appear in the same cell, surrounded by word boundaries.

Comment: My money's on the numbers not having spaces around them but that is the fun of this right?  If we're lucky the problem is so important to the user that they actually return.